# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, laravel

i want to store value to table but i have error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sisfo-ldii`.`nilai`, CONSTRAINT `fk_nilai_smp_sma_siswa1` FOREIGN KEY (`siswa_id`) REFERENCES `sisfo-ldii`.`siswa` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (SQL: insert into `nilai` (`siswa_id`, `input1`, `input2`, `input3`, `input4`, `input5`, `input6`, `input7`, `input8`, `input9`, `input10`, `input11`, `input12`, `input13`, `input14`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (14, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 2015-07-02 08:53:47, 2015-07-02 08:53:47))

here my controller:

```
public function storeKelas5()
{
    $nilai = new Nilai;
    $nilai->siswa_id = Input::get('siswa_id');
    $nilai->input1 = Input::get('input1');
    $nilai->input2 = Input::get('input2');
    $nilai->input3 = Input::get('input3');
    $nilai->input4 = Input::get('input4');
    $nilai->input5 = Input::get('input5');
    $nilai->input6 = Input::get('input6');
    $nilai->input7 = Input::get('input7');
    $nilai->input8 = Input::get('input8');
    $nilai->input9 = Input::get('input9');
    $nilai->input10 = Input::get('input10');
    $nilai->input11 = Input::get('input11');
    $nilai->input12 = Input::get('input12');
    $nilai->input13 = Input::get('input13');
    $nilai->input14 = Input::get('input14');
    $nilai->save();

    return redirect()->route('app.nilai.index');
}
```

and here my model:

```
public function siswa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Siswa', 'siswa_id');
}
```

Comment: Looks like the nilai->siswa_id value is not matching a row in the sisfo-ldii.siswa table

Comment: value id in "siswa" table matched

Answer (score 0):

try `$nilai = new nilai;` converted into `$nilai = new Nilai();` Because it is a model

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `foreign key constraint fails`

This is because you used a database name that used hyphen. Your database name is `sisfo-ldii`

Try to rename your database.

I suggest you to avoid using hyphen in for your database name and table name.

Comment: still error, i've changed my database to sisfo_ldii

Answer (score 0):

Have you also updated the foreign key constraint on nilai table to match the new table name - sisfo_ldii ?